# Accessing data in tables

Tags: matlab

I have a (fitted) linear mixed-effect model `lme` obtained via `fitlme`. In particular, I used

```
lme = fitlme(tbl, formula)
```

where `tbl` is a `table`.

I now pass this model to another function, which needs access to the original data. The data is in the `Variables` field of `lme`.

```
>> TT = lme.Variables; whos TT;
  Name          Size              Bytes  Class    Attributes
  TT        10415x29            8492068  table
```

So in `TT` I now have a table, which corresponds to the one used to fit the model.

According to Matlab documentation available [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html):

> T(rows,vars)  returns a table for one or more rows/variables
>
> T{rows,vars}  returns extracted data for one or more rows/variables

So, when I use `()` I get a table:

```
>> AA = lme.Variables(:, 'dist'); whos AA
  Name          Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
  AA        10415x1             85000  table
```

which is the expected behaviour according to the documentation.

If I use `{}`:

```
>> AA = lme.Variables{:, 'dist'}; whos AA
  Name          Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes    
  AA        10415x1             85000  table
```

I get a table again, but according to the doc I should receive a matrix containing the doubles in the column.

I know I can extract the same values with a different syntax:

```
>> AA = lme.Variables.('dist'); whos AA
  Name          Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes
  AA        10415x1             83320  double
```

but what did I miss in the doc concerning the two types of braces?

---

**Update**
This works:

```
lmeVars = lme.Variables; 
AA = lmeVars{:, 'dist'}; 
whos AA
  Name          Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes
  AA        12915x1             103320  double
```

I will never learn this programming language...

Comment: How about with this table: `x = table({'foo', 'bar', 'foo'}', [-1, 2, 4]', 'VariableNames', {'Name', 'Value'});`? On my machine (2015a), `y = x{:, 'Value'}; class(y)` gives `double`.

Comment: The result is `char`, after your edit it is `double` also here.

Comment: If the aboves gives `double`, then perhaps there is something particular about the `lme.Variables` table you have, something particular to `fitlme`? Are you able to post say `lme.Variables{1:5, 'dist'}`?

Comment: `lme.Variables{1:5, 'dist'}` still returns a `table`. May be there's something different to think about. Please see the edit.